# How to append milliseconds to the given date in moment js?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Is there any way to format the below date which has `HH:MM:SS` as time format into `HH:MM:SS:MMM` in moment js?

```
2016-01-10T00:00:00+05:30
```

Can it be converted into the format like the below one?

```
2016-01-10T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

Simple JS Code:

```js
var pop = moment('2016-01-03');
var pop1 = pop.add(1,'week');
console.log(pop1.format());
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you looked through their API docs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a custom string format argument to the [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method in order to customize format output. In your case you can do:

```
pop1.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

where `mm` means minutes (00..59), `ss` seconds (00..59) and `SSS` fractional seconds (000..999).

The docs says that if you do not pass any arguments to `format`:

> As of version **1.5.0**, calling `moment#format` without a format will default to `moment.defaultFormat`. Out of the box, `moment.defaultFormat` is the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`.

So if you want to change the way `format()` (without parameters) works, you can change `moment.defaultFormat`, for example:

```
moment.defaultFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ';
```

Here there is a live example:

```js
var pop = moment('2016-01-03');
var pop1 = pop.add(1,'week');

// By default format() wil give you results in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ
console.log(pop1.format()); // 2016-01-10T00:00:00+05:30
// You can pass a custom format string to the format method
console.log(pop1.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')); // 2016-01-10T00:00:00.000+05:30

// You can change defaultFormat according your needs
moment.defaultFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ';
console.log(pop1.format()); // 2016-01-10T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```